# Google pagespeed compress images served with proxy

Tags: .htaccess, proxy, reverse, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

We have a lot of product images on a content delivery network but want to compress them with pagespeed that is running on the web server. I have put an htaccess rule in place that proxies all images on the content delivery network through the web server.

```
 RewriteRule ^cdn/scdn/images/(.*) http://example.com/cdn/scdn/images/$1 [P,L]
```

The images are correctly being proxied however pagespeed 1.9.3 is not compressing them. I have tried adding

```
 ModPagespeedInPlaceResourceOptimization on
```

which should be turned on by default in the beta version anyway. I have also added

```
 ModPagespeedDomain mydomain.com
 ModPagespeedLoadFromFile "https://example.com" "/var/www/example"
 ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_images,lazyload_images,move_css_to_head,combine_css,inline_css,rewrite_javascript,defer_javascript,extend_cache
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

ModPagespeedMapProxyDomain https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/domains can do what I was trying to do